# serving static files with expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, middleware

This is my **code**:

`I want to hide my folder from client and put alias before file name`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')));
app.get('/',(req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'static','index.html'));
}).listen(3000);
```

when inspecting on chrome,it should give:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/public/css/main.css'>
<script src='/public/js/example.js'></script>
```

`But it is giving me:`

```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
   <script src='example.js'></script>
```

Comment: It's going to display the URLs that you typed into the HTML. I don't understand why you expect anything else.

Comment: u are not understanding the problem clearly

Comment: Let's put it this way: Why do you think the JavaScript you've provided have any influence over what the contents of the HTML document?

Comment: because we are using alias to hide our folder from client...it should display public before folder name

Comment: Your server side code gives a URL to a file. Your HTML document tells the browser what URL to ask for. Your server side code **does not edit the HTML at all** so it doesn't change what the HTML tells the browser to ask for. If your HTML tells the browser to ask for the wrong URL then you need to fix the HTML.

Comment: i watched the video of freecodecamp...It was working there

Comment: No idea what video that is but you must have misunderstood it.